# Copy contents of ostream to another ostream

Tags: c++, c++11, ostream

I'm looking for a method to copy the contents from one `ostream` to another.  I have the following code:

```
std::ostringsteam oss;

oss << "stack overflow";

{
    //do some stuff that may fail
    //if it fails, we don't want to create the file below!
}

std::ofstream ofstream("C:\\test.txt");

//copy contents of oss to ofstream somehow
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot. However, for your specific case, since your source `ostream` is actually `ostringstream`, you can. But that method is only applicable to `ostringstream`, not `ostream` in general.

Comment: How exactly do you want to copy *from* an **output** stream to another? You're not supposed to read from an output stream. There's no guarantee that it will work (in the precise case of an `ostringstream` it does, however).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything wrong with

```
ofstream << oss.str();
```

?

If you want to use the `ostream` base class then this isn't possible, as as far as an `ostream` is concerned anything that is written is gone forever. You will have to use something like:

```
// some function
...
  std::stringstream ss;

  ss << "stack overflow";
  ss.seekg(0, ss.beg);

  foo(ss);
...

// some other function
void foo(std::istream& is)
{
  std::ofstream ofstream("C:\\test.txt");
  ofstream << is.rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, basically I want a nice simple interface for a buffer to be filled and then, if the program doesn't run into an error, to write that buffer to a file.  This seems to do the trick.